# Login php retornando sempre vazio

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e tenho o seguinte problema: Eu cadastro um usuário, ele mostra no banco, ao tentar logar, mesmo preenchendo os campos corretamente, a **SESSION['em_branco']** retorna sempre no index.php e ainda mais... aparece os seguintes erros:

***Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\wamp64\www\app\php\login.php on line 4***
***Notice: Undefined index: senha in C:\wamp64\www\app\php\login.php on line 5***

**ARQUIVO LOGIN.PHP**

```
    <?php
require '../config/conexao.php';

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

if (isset($usuario) && !empty($usuario) && isset($senha) && !empty($senha)) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE USUARIO = :usuario AND SENHA = :senha";
    $query = $con->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(":usuario", $usuario);
    $query->bindValue(":senha", md5($senha));
    $query->execute();
    
    if ($query->rowCount() == 1) 
    {
        $user_logged = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        print_r($user_logged);

        $_SESSION["nome_usuario"] = $user_logged["USUARIO"];

        $_SESSION["logado"] = true;

        header('Location: ../pages/timeline.php');
        exit();
    } 
    else
    { 
        $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
        header('Location: ../index.php'); 
        exit();
    } 
}
else 
{
    $_SESSION['em_branco'] = true; 
    header('Location: ../index.php'); 
    exit();
} 

$con = null;
?>
```

**ARQUIVO INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <!-- JQUERY CDN -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- SLICK CSS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- FONTS AWESOME -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- ARQUIVO CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EAC | LOGIN</title>
  </head>
  <body id="primaryBody">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="logMessages text-center">
      <h1 class="logMessages_title mt-5 mb-4">WELCOME</h1>
      <p class="logMessages_subtitle mb-5">HAVE FUN AS YOU NEVER HAVE FUN WHILE STUDYING</p>
    </div>

    <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="card shadow p-2" style="width: 20rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="logForm">
            <h3 class="mb-4">LOG IN</h3>

            <!-- PHP CASO A AUTENTICAÇÃPO FALHE ELE IMPRIME NA TELA -->
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['nao_autenticado'])) { ?>
              <!-- MENSAGEM DE ERRO -->
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <p>Usuário ou senha inválidos.</p>
              </div>
              <!-- FIM MENSAGEM DE ERRO -->
            <?php } unset($_SESSION['nao_autenticado']); ?>
            <!-- FIM DO PHP DE FALHA NA AUTENTICAÇÃO -->

            <!-- PHP CASO A AUTENTICAÇÃPO FALHE ELE IMPRIME NA TELA -->
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['em_branco'])) { ?>
              <!-- MENSAGEM DE ERRO -->
              <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <p>Preencha todos os campos.</p>
              </div>
              <!-- FIM MENSAGEM DE ERRO -->
            <?php } unset($_SESSION['em_branco']); ?>
            <!-- FIM DO PHP DE FALHA NA AUTENTICAÇÃO -->

            <form class="logForm_form" action="php/login.php" method="post">
              <div class="logForm_form_column">
                <input class="mb-4" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuario">
                <input class="mb-4" type="password" placeholder="Senha" name="senha">
              </div>
              <div class="logForm_form_row justify-content-between mb-4">
                <div class="logForm_form_row_texts">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="scales">
                  <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="btnLogin">LOGIN</button>
              <a class="btn btn-success mb-2" id="btnLogin" href="pages/register.php">REGISTER</a>
              <a class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnLogin" href="pages/timeline.php">CONVIDADO</a>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ARQUIVO JS -->
  <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Espero ansiosamente que alguém me ajude, grato desde já.

Comment: Nao deveria ter ```type=submit```  no botao LOGIN?

Comment: Não é necessário pois é o único button dentro do formulário, sendo assim ja é um submit, os outros são apenas links estilizados de botões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, além de retirar a $_SESSION que cuida dos campos vazios eu substitui ela por um REQUIRED na tag input HTML, isso fez com que nao houvesse erros na query, na session e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Obs: botao não necessita de submit quando é o único do formulário, ou seja, por sua vez, automaticamente já é um submit.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o erro é por não haver nenhum botão type="submit", sendo assim, os dados do formulário podem não estar passando corretamente para o arquivo que recebe os dados, fazendo com que

$variável = $_POST['campo'];

não receba nenhum valor e dê erro.

Tenta colocar SUBMIT no botão LOGIN

Comment: Não funcionou, Jerfeson

Comment: Hoje mais cedo posso tentar refazer seu código aqui para lhe ajudar, se você quiser é claro. Vc ainda vai querer?

Comment: Acho que sei onde está seu erro. Tenho 8p% de certeza. Não é nada no php pelo que creio

Comment: Quero ajuda sim, é um projeto pessoal de importância.

Comment: Onde seria esse erro?

Comment: Olá, Jeferson, conseguiu achar algo?